# PATH not updated correctly from conda activate in VSCode's terminal

Tags: python, path, visual-studio-code, conda

I am using VSCodes terminal pane. I activate a conda environment. For some reason, the `python` command is still set to `/usr/bin/python`, instead of the correct path to the conda environment.

```
% conda activate myenv
% which python
/usr/bin/python
```

The correct anaconda environment directory does seem  to be in the `$PATH` variable, but `/usr/bin` seems above it in priority.

When I open a standard terminal through the OS, the behavior is as I expect.

```
% conda activate myenv
% which python
/Users/cpl/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python
```

Please note: I have already set the VSCode preferences key `python.pythonPath` to `/Users/cpl/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python`, and I think that it works correctly. When I run a file through right-clicking and selecting `Run Python File In Terminal`, the correct python (from the conda environment) is executed.  My problem is using the VSCode terminal directly to execute python.

My shell is zsh, and I am using OSX. Any advice?

Comment: I would double-check that `echo $SHELL` is the same in both to make sure that the magic bit that is supposed to be in your shell config as specified by https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell has been executed.

Comment: Yeah, I have that "magic" bit that runs `conda.sh` in my `.zshrc` file. The $SHELL variable is `/bin/zsh` in both the vscode terminal and system terminal.

Comment: Hmm, there's obviously some disconnect, but the Python extension doesn't directly manipulate terminal startup so we aren't going to be the ones causing the issue (the only thing we do is run commands in the terminal, but you will visibly see that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is explained in the VSCode docs:
[Why are there duplicate paths in the terminal's $PATH environment variable and/or why are they reversed?#](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_why-are-there-duplicate-paths-in-the-terminals-path-environment-variable-andor-why-are-they-reversed)

It sounds like VSCode will run your .zshrc twice in MacOS, conflicting with the conda-generated `PATH` variable definitions.

There are two solutions listed in the link above. The one that works for me is to set the VSCode setting `"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false`. The documentation warns that all of your environmental variables will be stripped if you do this. However, I find I still have my custom variables defined in the `.zshrc` file.

It is worth noting that recent versions of VSCode will prompt you when it detects you are using a conda environment, and suggests making this change.

Comment: I'll admit I still don't quite understand the cause.  I don't entirely understand why VSCode doesn't just start a fresh terminal session, rather than inheriting environment details from the parent VSCode session. Adding to the confusion, most of the explanations I found was for pre-zsh MacOS.  Since ZSH and Bash handle the *profile and *rc files differently, I wasn't sure how much of those explanations still applied.

Comment: If someone can provide an answer that explains the problem better, I'll set that as the correct answer rather than my own.

Answer (score 2):

A dark magic below may work:-

In my Big Sur, I added the following empty entry to my settings.json -- can be found at File(Windows)/Code(Mac)>Preferences>Settings -- click on any link stated "Edit in settings.json"

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PATH": ""
}
```

All the best!

Comment: Ok this works, but why is it necessary? Why doesn't VSCode source .zsh, which would run the conda commands and set the PATH appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use zsh, but I've run into this issue in bash and I believe the cause is the same.

Conda has recently changed the "official" method of activating environments, as described in this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1882

Before, you needed to modify your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`  to prepend `PATH` with the directory of conda's `activate` script, and then activate specific environments by typing `source activate name_of_env`. VSCode-Python activates conda terminals by sending this command to the shell — with visible echo, like you typed it yourself.

The new method is to source `$HOME/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` in `.bashrc` and then activate environments with `conda activate name_of_env`, which is the behavior you're seeing work correctly in a dedicated terminal. VSCode-Python does not yet support this, and there appear to be issues with cross-platform support on Windows that are complicating the transition.

The best solution for now is to ignore the "correct" method of `conda activate` and consistently use the older `source activate name_of_env`, which still works (if your `PATH` is set to include `$HOME/anaconda3/bin`).

Comment: Had to do three out of all options provided to make this work --- STEP-1 --- deleted the Line from ~./bashrc                                                                                                                                   `export PATH="/home/dhankar/anaconda2/bin:$PATH" `  STEP -2 --- `sudo ln -s /home/dhankar/anaconda2/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh`      STEP-3--- `echo ". /home/dhankar/anaconda2/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @RohitDhankar What is the 2nd step for?
For anaconda3, step 1 and step 3 are still applicable for a proper configuration of conda (on my macbook anaconda3 is installed in ~/opt/anaconda3, however).

Comment: @amka66 - Old issue STEP-2 was some symlink i would have done back then . Sorry dont recollect it now .

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else in the future ends up scratching their heads over this particular problem, I’ve found another culprit:

[image: Showcase of setting]
Terminal>Integrated>Env: Enable Persistent Sessions

I suspect what happens is that after you update system paths, VScode caches the old path in the terminal and persists it. In this case it persists the old python path rather than the new conda one.

Toggling this option off and restarting VSCode clears that cache, and the new path is loaded in. You can also toggle the option back on after you’re done.