# How to activate the current venv (not by conda/venv) in terminal VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, jupyter-notebook, python-venv

I'm using the virtual environment created from Pycharm as interpreter for my jupyter notebook project in VSCode. The venv hasn't been created by either conda or virtualenv so I cannot activate the venv in VSCode terminal as usual such as `conda activate venv_name` or `. /Scripts/activate.bat`...
Could anyone give a hand on how to activate the current venv/interpreter in terminal VSCode? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Bruce, sorry, then I did not get your problem correctly. Thanks for pointing out. I withdrew my incorrect answer.

Comment: Hi Kai, no problem, cheers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comment. Yep, I also feel hard on explaining it myself. What i need actually is I would like to run in VScode terminal this command `zipline ingest -b 'mybundle'` in the python3.6 environment. I tried to run it on Jupyter as `!zipline ingest -b 'mybundle'` but causing an error...Lucky me that **tromgy** absolutely giving me the answer as below, in the chat section
I will try to describe better for the next concerns, cheers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PATH not updated correctly from conda activate in VSCode's terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51792387/path-not-updated-correctly-from-conda-activate-in-vscodes-terminal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find where that PyCharm environment is located -- use the **Run > Edit Configurations** menu, and look in the **Python interpreter** box:

[image: PyCharm screenshot]

There should be some script, such as **activate** in that location.

Comment: Hi tromgy, unlucky that I cannot file the activate file or any file ".bat" in the /Python3.6/Scripts/ or in the entire project, that's why I cannot activate it on terminal. Do you have any other idea?

Comment: Then it looks like you have a "bare/pure" Python 3.6 that you use in PyCharm. It's not a "virtual enviroment" that you can activate, but just a base interperter with whatever packages that got installed with it. In this case you should be able to invoke it from the VS Code terminal just by using the full path to the interpreter.

Comment: It is absolutely right about the "bare/pure" python3.6, I dont know how to describe that. But could you just abit more detailed about **invoke it from the VS Code terminal just by using the full path to the interpreter**. Is that by using `cd /interpreter_full_path/` then it means I already in the current python3.6 environment?

Comment: I don't know what OS you have, but this interpreter can already be on your path, or you can just give the full path in the terminal. For example on macOS, my "default" Python setup as 3.9.1 -- that's what I get if I just type `python` in the terminal. But, if I need say 3.6 I can just use the `python3.6` command. But knowing the full path to it I can also use `/usr/local/bin/python3.6` in the terminal. That way there's no doubt which Python it is.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Win10. I changed directory to the folder containing python.exe (python3.6) then just typed `python`, it then activated python3.6 with all installed dependencies. You definitely lead me to the solution, thank you tromgy!! Unlucky that I haven't got enough reputation for voting for you, cheers.